# One page wikis to store all the chat room's nuggets and references

Tags: feature-request, chat

Chat rooms should have some kind of page that captures all the essence and go-to questions that can often come up, but aren't easily searched.

A reference point. A one page wiki.

The page should be editable only by the room owners, but visible to all that have normal viewing access.

This would allow for private moderator rooms to have a quick list of common scenarios or situations and their answers, that might not be good things to post on any meta, even if obscured.

Or they can have the room's few golden rules, because the room description doesn't allow long messages and pins that are constantly being repeated are constantly being repeated. Or who to contact on the team for various things.

Info currently gives you the overview of the whos and the whens of the room, but a one page wiki can be like the guiding hand or [Teachers' Editions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separate_Vocations).

It could sit right next to that "info" link, something like "real info" or "room faq" and any changes get pipped into the main so that you can all know what's going on when any editing has been going on.

It could even be [shoved into a new user's face](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104590/detect-new-users-to-chat-display-helpful-info) upon their first entry into the room so that they can ignore it like they do all FAQs.

Comment: Can't see why this would be a problem, I like it!

Comment: Brilliant! I haven't used the chat rooms very much in my time on SE (1+ year). I think this would be very very useful to new users to the SE network in general, as well as users like me who have little experience with the chat rooms. I've wondered things like *is it okay to speak English in French.SE chat if I can't think of the right vocabulary? Is that offensive to the users there?* Right away I can say *no* just because I (think that I) know some users there who are very friendly in regards to helping others learn French. But it's not obvious... wikis would be **very** appreciated.